# Xcode 12 Push notification toggle empty

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode12

I facing a problem with Xcode 12.1 .. when I add the Push Notification from `+ Capability` the push notification button is hidden !! when I add it on my project it seems to be disabled !

[image]

Some body have facing this problem yet ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no button, it's working properly.